# Jetpack Paging 3 RemoteMediator is calling LoadType.APPEND for other fragments when I refresh in current active fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3

I have a Fragment with a ViewPager2( using FragmentStateAdapter). The ViewPager itself holds a dynamic number of fragments. Each Fragment is for one category of data. After I open multiple fragments and swipe-to-refresh on any of the fragments( calling `PagingAdapter.refresh()`), the RemoteMediator clears the table as expected and reloads the page but it calls LoadType.APPEND for the other active fragments as well, resulting in those fragment to load next pages for those categories and creating a bad jumpy experience while scrolling.

I have tried using the latest version of the paging library - **androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-beta01** but that doesn't solve the problem either.

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Edit 1: There is no way to get inside the `refresh()` code so I haven't been able to figure out what exactly is happening inside the hood.